# Using temp table check records exist or not – if present then do the same operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

If records are present or not present, then those records should be inserted into temp table along with status. **I am looking for very high performance query, because this SP is being called online with many users.  Please help me.**

I have a temp table and one master table, and I need to compare with master table, if the records present then status should be "Valid", if not present, then status needs to be "Invalid".

`MainRecords`: in this table `CorrectNumber` column might be repeated with different dates as mentioned below:

I am looking for final output should be like below :

`#TempReferencIds`:

```
'8273648','3333333',’INVALID’
'3434448','1111111', ’INVALID’
'2244448','2222222', ’INVALID’
'10101010','7003594558',’VALID’
'20202020','7003310682',’VALID’
'30303030','6130985705',’VALID’
```

This is what I have tried – but it is not showing the correct result which I am expecting as mentioned above table :

```
CREATE TABLE MainRecords
(
        CorrectNumber nvarchar(20),
        name nvarchar(20),
        Date nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('7003594558', 'sssss', GETDATE())
INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('7003310682', 'gfdga', GETDATE())
INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('7003310682', 'gfdga', GETDATE()- 17)
INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('6130985705', 'fdgfd', GETDATE())
INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('6130985705', 'fdgfd', GETDATE()-1)
INSERT INTO MainRecords VALUES ('6130985705', 'fdgfd', GETDATE()-3)

CREATE TABLE #InputRecords
(
    InCorrectNumber varchar(20),
    CorrectNumber nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('8273648', '3333333')
INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('3434448', '1111111')
INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('2244448', '2222222')
INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('10101010', '7003594558')
INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('20202020', '7003310682')
INSERT INTO #InputRecords VALUES ('30303030', '6130985705')

CREATE TABLE #TempReferencIds
(
    InCorrectNumber varchar(20),
    CorrectNumber nvarchar(20),
    Status nvarchar(10),
)

IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 
           FROM [dbo].MainRecords a 
           JOIN #InputRecords b ON a.CorrectNumber = b.CorrectNumber)) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TempReferencIds (InCorrectNumber, CorrectNumber, Status)
        SELECT t.InCorrectNumber, t.CorrectNumber, 'VALID' 
        FROM [dbo].MainRecords a 
        JOIN #InputRecords t ON a.CorrectNumber = t.CorrectNumber
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO #TempReferencIds (InCorrectNumber, CorrectNumber, Status)
         SELECT t.InCorrectNumber, t.CorrectNumber, 'INVALID' 
         FROM [dbo].MainRecords a 
         JOIN #InputRecords t ON a.CorrectNumber <> t.CorrectNumber
END

SELECT * FROM #TempReferencIds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query below

```
INSERT INTO #TempReferencIds (InCorrectNumber, CorrectNumber, Status)
SELECT t.InCorrectNumber, t.CorrectNumber, 'VALID' 
FROM [dbo].MainRecords a 
JOIN #InputRecords t ON a.CorrectNumber = t.CorrectNumber
UNION
SELECT t.InCorrectNumber, t.CorrectNumber, 'INVALID' 
FROM [dbo].MainRecords a 
RIGHT JOIN #InputRecords t ON a.CorrectNumber = t.CorrectNumber
WHERE a.CorrectNumber IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this all in one join.  It looks like you're trying to do this only with INNER JOINs, you need a left join.

```
SELECT  I.InCorrectNumber, I.CorrectNumber, CASE WHEN M.CorrectNumber IS NOT    NULL THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END 'Status'
FROM #InputRecords I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MainRecords M ON ( M.CorrectNumber = I.CorrectNumber )
```

The #InputRecords is always there, the MainRecords are sometimes there.  You check if there is a record in MainRecords ( CorrectNumber is not null ) to get the status.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for creating easily consumable data structures and sample data. It makes helping so much easier.

I would shorten your query to a single insert statement instead of two. Something along these lines should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO #TempReferencIds (InCorrectNumber, CorrectNumber, Status)
select distinct mr.CorrectNumber 
    , ir.CorrectNumber
    , case when mr.CorrectNumber = ir.CorrectNumber then 'Valid' else 'InValid' end
from dbo.MainRecords mr
full outer join #InputRecords ir on mr.CorrectNumber = ir.CorrectNumber
where exists
(
    select *
    from dbo.MainRecords mr2
    join #InputRecords ir2 on ir2.CorrectNumber = mr2.CorrectNumber
)
```

Comment: Thank you Sean for responding on this , I noticed that in your query final result I am seeing duplicate data for the 'CorrectNumber' column , Basically as I mentioned initially I am looking for non duplicate records in CorrectNumber column in the final temptable - Can you please help me. These 2 records (7003310682,6130985705) are getting duplicated in final table - Kindly help me

Comment: That isn't a problem. Just add distinct to avoid duplicates. See the updated code.

Comment: Sure, I am fine . Thank you again for the response